# Request to increase quota for c2 cpus failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

I kept requesting quota increase for c2 cpus
It's failing again and again.
I keep getting answers like this.

> ...did not find any changes that needed to be made. This could be due to
> being unable  to fulfill part of the request. If you would like to
> reduce your quota, please reply to this message and a support
> representative will get back to you. If  the current values are still
> insufficient, please file a new request with a  reduced ask or
> additional justification.

Comment: Can you tell me where (in which region / zone) that you made the quota request? As well it appears in your post that the message that you said you got was cut off at the beginning. Could you edit your question so I can see the full message? I have included a link here, [it’s Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) , have you been able to follow it? It should be noted that there is a waiting period of 24 to 48 hours for quota requests.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Server Fault community can do nothing with such issues. You should reach Google Cloud to solve this issue.

You're dealing with a credit situation. Is your credit good enough to justify a cloud vendor allowing access to resources that you pay for later? Review the credit card that you posted to your billing account. Does it only have $10.00 in credit available or are you using a corporate debit card? Are you a hobbyist or a business? How long has your account been open? These are factors that companies might consider in granting a credit line increase.

**To solve this issue** you can try steps below:

- Try to work for a while with current quotas, if it possible for your use case, to get some history on your account and after that [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).
- Try to split desired increase in quota into some steps that could be approved like 2 -> 4 -> 8 and so on
- Try to reach [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).
- Try to reply again to `gc-team@google.com` but provide some arguments to clarify your request.

Keep in mind, that **you're not able to change quota if you're using** [90-day, $300 Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial). To be able to request an increase in quota, you must [upgrade to a paid account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).